# Android MediaRecorder prepare failed -17

Tags: android

I am trying to capture video and encode it using Android `MediaRecorder`.But when I am getting
prepare failed:

```
-17
java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
```

Here is my code:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test.mp4");
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
mediaRecorder.prepare();
```

**When i set VideoEncoder to H263 and Outputformat to THREE_GPP i am not getting this exception**.

Here is the complete stacktrace.

```
E/mm-camera 7x-vfe(   68): Received VFE start ACK!!! This is a user preview start.

D/QualcommCameraHardware(   68): startPreview X
E/AuthorDriver(   68): Command 13 completed with error -17
E/MediaRecorder( 6406): prepare failed: -17
W/System.err( 6406): java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:509)
W/System.err( 6406):    at org.video.VideoStreamSender.prepare(VideoStreamSender.java:50)
W/System.err( 6406):    at org.video.VideoPreview.surfaceCreated(VideoPreview.java:50)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:540)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:339)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
W/System.err( 6406):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
W/System.err( 6406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
W/System.err( 6406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 6406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err( 6406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/System.err( 6406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
W/System.err( 6406):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/CameraService(   68): [Camera KPI] 1st preview frame
```

Comment: Can you provide larger stacktrace, preferably by editing your question?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to set a camera to the media recorder before you set the sources and formats?
something like this:

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

(maybe it's necessary to unlock the camera)

```
    (camera.unlock();)

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    ...
```

In my case it works.